# Fast OpenCV Array Increment for Repeated Indices (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, indexing

I need to increment an OpenCV array `image` according to indices held in another object Y. Now Y, may contain *repeated indices* i.e. these locations should be incremented multiple times. Y is typically 100000 elements. Currently this is solved with a simple for loop as follows:

```
for (const auto& e: Y)
{
   image.at<float>(e.y, e.x) += 1; 
}
```

This piece of code is called many times and is currently a bottleneck in my application. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: so, you want to reduce (operations on) Y by finding duplicates ?

Comment: how often does Y get updated, wrt. image ? how do you collect Y ? why not use a std::map with index as key and (accumulated) count as value ?

Comment: There is an outer loop (not shown) which changes the coordinates held in Y 50 times. For each of these 50 versions of Y, the image incrementer loop is called, meaning  50 * ~100000 image updates. Y is output from an API that I can't change.